# cannot execute binary file

Tags: terminal, bash

I have a simple binary file needs to be executed. So I opened terminal and navigate to the folder where the binary file is. Then I gave the command `./bclock` and got the following error,

```
-bash: ./bclock: cannot execute binary file
```

After some research I though it has something to do with echo $PATH. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

The two common problems are that the permissions are wrong or the file is somehow corrupt.

You can add execute permission (or list them) with the two commands:

```
chmod a+x ./bclock
ls -l ./bclock
```

You can check the file format as well to see if it's really executable or if it's a script or other type.

```
file ./bclock
```